# Using 'this' keyword in constructor

Tags: c#

What is the difference b/w the following two codes. What is the use of using 'this' keyword in the constructor.

**Ex 1:**

```
public Product(string name){
this.Name = name;
}
```

**Ex 2:**

```
public Product(string name){
Name = name;
}
```

I know this refers to the calling object. Just I couldn't able to get the difference?

can some one please explain?

Comment: "To qualify members hidden by similar names". It is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dk1507sz(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example 1 uses an explicit reference to `this`. This is not really needed as there's no ambiguity in this case. If the parameter was called `Name` instead, the explicit `this` would be required to resolve the ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

It is absolutely optional in the example you provide.

Mainly, it implicitely tells the user that the member that is worked with is part of the current class object.

One practice was to differentiate parameters from members or fields like the following:

```
public class Customer {
    private string name;

    public Customer(string name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 
}
```

For readability's sake, one would put `this` in front of the `name` field to make it clear that the value of the `name` parameter is assigned to the **this** class' `name` field.

In such situation, it is necessery, as both the constructor parameter and the field have the same name. Otherwise, if they were different variable names, the `this` keyword would be optional.

Comment: In the example you've given here, "this" is *not* optional - the code has different meaning with and without the "this".

Comment: Second for "this" not being optional in this particular example.

Comment: I expose a situation where it is not optional, indeed, and that is what I wanted to tell the OP. With different names (field and constructor parameter), `this` becomes optional. I don't get the downvotes...

Comment: I took off my down vote.  Your edit makes your point much clearer.

Comment: I agree, and have removed my downvote too. Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 3):

In that case, there's no difference. The more common reason for being explicit is something like this:

```
public Product(string name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

At that point the `this` is absolutely required, otherwise it would be a no-op assignment from the parameter to itself (which would raise a warning, IIRC).

Answer (score 2):

In terms of emitted IL absolutely no difference. It's just for readability. When you use `this` you are more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

`this.Name` is more explicit than just `Name`. Using `this` makes it more obvious as to what the code is doing; but in this case the compiler will interpret them the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with other here who say using "this" is more explicit. It is most definitely **not**. In the examples you gave, the property "Name" is as explicit as it gets. If we had another keyword that had more letters than "this" it wouldn't be more explicit.

```
Name
```

is no less explicit than

```
this.Name
```

which is also no less explicit than the following nonsense

```
thisIsNotAKeyWordButItMeansThis.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of style.  Like the others have said, there is no difference in the IL.  Personally, I like to see the `this.` prefix used whenever accessing members of the class.  In fact, the default StyleCop rules require it.  It just makes it clear where the member is coming from.