# Is there a difference between using 'this' keyword in the constructor of a class or not using it in C++

Tags: c++, this

**Posts that I have read that are related to my question and have answered part of it:**

[Using 'this' keyword in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227757/using-this-keyword-in-constructor)

[Difference between using keyword new in constructor and in data portion of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736035/difference-between-using-keyword-new-in-constructor-and-in-data-portion-of-a-cla)

**My question:**

My specific question follows on from the topic here:

[Using 'this' keyword in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227757/using-this-keyword-in-constructor)

Are the answers provided in that topic regarding ambiguity the same for C++? Does it only matter that I use `this` if my parameter has the same name as my field?

Here is an example with the `this` keyword:

```
    Gui::Gui()
    {
        this->organismSize = 10.0;
        this->foodSize = 5.0;
    }
```

Without the `this` keyword:

```
    Gui::Gui()
    {
        organismSize = 10.0;
        foodSize  5.0;
    }
```

Comment: If you insist on using the same names for parameters and member variables then only the first version will work.  Otherwise, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Now you have changed the question to make my comment invalid.  I would prefer it if you didn't do that.  Anyway, with your amended code, both versions have the same effect.

Comment: @PaulSanders The code was incorrect, if if I didnt change it then I wouldnt be asking the right question. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The more typing your do, the higher probability of injecting defects into your code.  You can avoid using `this->` syntax by choosing a naming convention that differentiates member variables from parameters, such as prepending "m_" or appending "_" to member variable names.

Comment: `this` is implied when used for a member variable (because non static member variables only exist within the object created, so 'this' is always there) so the question is only depending on the scope being hidden by another variable (in your case, the parameter)

Comment: Use this keyword to resolve some ambiguity. You should first use member inizializer list : organismSize{10.0} if you do this : organismSize{ organismSize } the first is the class member and the other one is the constructor parameter.

Comment: @PaulSanders or you could initialise members in the member initialiser list, where it is unambiguous

Comment: "Posts that I have read that are related to my question and have answered part of it:" The posts are **not** related to your question and **don't** answer any of your questions! The posts you linked are about C# and Java and you are asking about C++. Although somewhat related, they are different languages! Just check this topic, but for C++, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435693/constructor-and-this-pointer

Comment: @bolov They are related because they answer the issue for those languages which is why I asked if the same applies for C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use 'this' keyword in the constructor unless you have the same name for a class attribute and a parameter.

```
Gui::Gui(const double organismSize, const double foodSize )
{
    organismSize =organismSize; // we have an ambiguity, the compiler cannot make a difference between the parameter and the attribute
    foodSize = foodSize ;
}

Gui::Gui(const double organismSize, const double foodSize )
{
    this->organismSize =organismSize; // the compiler can make a difference between the parameter and the attribute
    //this->organismSize is the attribute while organismSize is the parameter
    this->foodSize = foodSize ;
}
```

Comment: If you initialize members with an initializer list, as you should, you don’t need `this` to disambiguate.

Answer (score 2):

The previous (accepted) answer is incorrect!

The main reason of using `this` to access the members of the class is when this class is a template, and the base class depends of the template parameter. Consider this code:

```cpp
struct Base {
    Base ()
      : m_baseMember(42) {}
    int m_baseMember;
};

int m_baseMember;

struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived() {
        m_baseMember = 0;
        m_derivedMember = 0;
    }

    int m_derivedMember;
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    cout << d.m_baseMember << ' ' << d.m_derivedMember << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code obviously outputs `0 0`, as the assignment `m_baseMember = 0;` affects the member of the `Base` class.

Now a very similar code, but the base class becomes a template, and I instantiate it with `int`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Base {
    Base ()
      : m_baseMember(42) {}
    int m_baseMember;
};

int m_baseMember;

struct Derived : public Base<int> {
    Derived() {
        m_baseMember = 0;
        m_derivedMember = 0;
    }

    int m_derivedMember;
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    cout << d.m_baseMember << ' ' << d.m_derivedMember << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Again the output is `0 0`. Ok, let's move on. Both `Base` and `Derived` are templates...

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Base {
    Base ()
      : m_baseMember(42) {}
    int m_baseMember;
};

int m_baseMember;

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<int> {
    Derived() {
        m_baseMember = 0;
        m_derivedMember = 0;
    }

    int m_derivedMember;
};

int main() {
    Derived<int> d;
    cout << d.m_baseMember << ' ' << d.m_derivedMember << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `0 0` again. Nothing could go wrong with this code! One more attempt: now the `Derived` inherits from `Base<T>` (and not from `Base<int>`):

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Base {
    Base ()
      : m_baseMember(42) {}
    int m_baseMember;
};

int m_baseMember;

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T> {
    Derived() {
        m_baseMember = 0;
        m_derivedMember = 0;
    }

    int m_derivedMember;
};

int main() {
    Derived<int> d;
    cout << d.m_baseMember << ' ' << d.m_derivedMember << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is... `42 0`.

That is because in this very-very-very similar code the assignment `m_baseMember = 0;` is being applied to the global variable. The final snippet where we explicitly use `this`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Base {
    Base ()
      : m_baseMember(42) {}
    int m_baseMember;
};

int m_baseMember;

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T> {
    Derived() {
        this->m_baseMember = 0;
        m_derivedMember = 0;
    }

    int m_derivedMember;
};

int main() {
    Derived<int> d;
    cout << d.m_baseMember << ' ' << d.m_derivedMember << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `0 0` again, because `this->m_baseMember = 0;` obviously affects the class member.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this looks like a very complicated way to shoot oneself in the foot.

Comment: @VincentFourmond, the way to shoot yourself in the foot is avoiding `this` whenever working with template classes. That is why MUCH safer is to access the template class members using `this`.

Comment: Hmmm. I get your point, but this is only going to cause troubles inside complicated hierarchies of template classes, which is probably not what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @VincentFourmond, the question was: "Is there a difference between using 'this' keyword in the constructor of a class or not using it in C++". And the MAIN reason of using `this` keyword is to access the members of template classes. That is the idiomatic way to access them, because of possible latent errors.

Comment: As an aside, *two-phase lookup* is the key-term.